# How can I get a messagedialog to call another subroutine in Windows Store Apps using VB?

Tags: vb.net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Async Sub cmdAppBarLogout_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles cmdAppBarLogout.Click
Dim message As New MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to logout?", "Logout confirmation")    

        message.Commands.Add(New UICommand("Yes"))

        message.Commands.Add(New UICommand("No"))    

        Await message.ShowAsync
End Sub


Private Sub Logout()
        session.StaffInfo = Nothing
        Frame.Navigate(GetType(Login))
End Sub
```

When a user clicks on the "Yes" button, I would like the Logout Sub to be called though I am not sure how to do this. I have found many examples relating to C# and C++ though a VB one does not seem to exist. Please help.

I am aware that the "message.Commands.Add(New UICommand(" function has extra parameters though I am not sure how to use them correctly.

Comment: ShowAsync returns a value that tells you which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UICommand has multiple constructors that can specify a callback handler for when the command is invoked. The code you provided is not using a constructor that specifies such a handler.

I've included code below that shows how to specify a callback handler in the UICommand. Each command could have a method of its own, share the same method, or have no method at all.

```
...
    message.Commands.Add(New UICommand("Yes", AddressOf Me.CommandInvokedHandler))
    message.Commands.Add(New UICommand("No"))
...

Private Sub CommandInvokedHandler(command As IUICommand)
    ' Run the appropriate code based on the callback here.
    ' If this handler is shared between multiple commands, use command.Label
    ' or command.Id to determine which command is being invoked.
    Logout
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response though I am getting the following error: Error 7 Too many arguments to 'Public Sub Add(item As T)'. Have you tested this code yourself by any chance?

Comment: Fixed in my response - two arguments should have been provided to the UICommand constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Your new solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with this.

```
message.Commands.Add(New UICommand("Yes", AddressOf Logout))
```

Check out the [MSDN sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Message-dialog-sample-4e6eca6b/sourcecode?fileId=86111&pathId=1306562810)

Comment: I have tried this and I get the following error: Error 7 Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

Comment: If you using above statement in more than one line then you need to add "_" at the end of each line that is not the last one. the underscore is the continuation character. The above code works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I figured out why your code was not initially working on my side - it was due to the fact that I had not added the "command As IUICommand" parameter to the Logout Sub. Otherwise, it now works as you suggested.